# Trouble with PHP, PDO, and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a script to add an item to a shopping cart..

I want to first check to see if there's an existing cart table for the user. If not, I want to create a new table for the shopping cart.

If there is already a table, I want to see if the current item is already in it. If it is, then I just want to update the quantity. If it's not already in the table, then I want to add a new row.

In the code below, the UPDATE statement is firing whether there is an `itemNumber` match or not. This means that there's no exception, and that the new row is not being inserted for new the new `itemNumber`. Everything else is working as expected.

```
try {

    // create the shopping cart. If it already exists, throw an exception

    $cartDb->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); //Error Handling
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `' . $table . '` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `itemNumber` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `price` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `color` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `size` CHAR(20), `quantity` INT(5) NOT NULL, `category` TEXT NOT NULL, `photo` TEXT NOT NULL);';
    $cartDb->exec($sql);

    try {

        // if you get this far then the cart has been newly created. Insert the item information into the cart

        $cartDb->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` (`itemNumber`, `title`, `price`, `color`, `size`, `quantity`, `category`, `photo`) VALUES ("' . $itemNumber . '", "' . $title . '", "' . $price . '", "' . $color . '", "' . $size . '", "' . $quantity . '", "' . $category . '", "' . $photo . '");';
        $cartDb->exec($sql);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        // we got an exception == could not insert the data into the table

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    // we got an exception == table already exists

    echo $e->getMessage();

    try {

        // first see if the item number is already in the table

        $cartDb->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "UPDATE `" . $table . "` SET `quantity` = `quantity` + " . $quantity . " WHERE `itemNumber` = '" . $itemNumber . "'";
        $cartDb->exec($sql);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        // exception thrown == item number is not yet in the table

        echo $e->getMessage();

        try {

            $cartDb->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` (`itemNumber`, `title`, `price`, `color`, `size`, `quantity`, `category`, `photo`) VALUES ("' . $itemNumber . '", "' . $title . '", "' . $price . '", "' . $color . '", "' . $size . '", "' . $quantity . '", "' . $category . '", "' . $photo . '");';
            $cartDb->exec($sql);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage();

        }

    }   

}
```

Comment: Whatever else is wrong here, you shouldn't be creating and dropping tables on the fly. Use a single table for all carts and distinguish individual carts by a user ID of some description.

Comment: I would assign the value of your `exec()` statement to a variable like: `$return = $cartDb->exec($sql);` then echo that variable. I believe if no rows are updated then it returns `0` (the count of the affected rows) and not an exception.

Comment: Thank you @ride_85027 that got things working for me.

Comment: Great, good to hear. I just added it as an answer for future readers then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign the value of your `exec()` statement to a variable like: `$return = $cartDb->exec($sql);` then echo that variable.

I believe if no rows are updated then it returns `0` for the count of the affected rows and not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of the statements:
Simply put the INSERT before the UPDATE, because the INSERT will catch an exception if the record already exists. The UPDATE won't.

Comment: That makes sense. The answer above got things working for me so I chose that as the correct answer, but this would probably work as well.